# Getting notifications for 2 villages on clash of clans

Tags: clash-of-clans

I had a CoC account that I transferred over from my iPad to my Galaxy S4 and linked it to a g+ account but wanted to start fresh on the S4 so I deleted app data and created a new G+ account and linked it to the new G+ account, everything went okay but I still seem to be getting notifications on my S4 for my old account thats currently on my iPad.

I then I deleted the all G+ accounts off my S4 apart from the new one that has my new clash of clans village and I then cleared app data and app cache and loaded my village using the new G+ account and I'm still getting notifications for the old village!

It's very annoying.

Anyway to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: if you started on an iPad, log into game center, you should be able to change CoC's notification settings.  Not sure it's possible without the game installed though.

Comment: If you transferred your game with "Link a Device"  you'll have to contact Supercell support to get them to break the link.  No other way to do it.